# translate query from MSSQL to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i have following query that i need to translate from MSSQL to MYSQL

```
select TOP 7500 Verdunster1B_Digital.LocalCol,
       Verdunster1B_Digital.Funktion_Heizband_Verdunster1B,
       Maschinenraum_Digital.Funktion_Ventilatoren_Verdampfer_Msr,
       Maschinenraum_Digital.Funktion_Glykolpumpe1_Tankverbindung
from Verdunster1B_Digital
  inner join Maschinenraum_Digital 
          on DateAdd (Millisecond,- DatePart (Millisecond,Maschinenraum_Digital.LocalCol),Maschinenraum_Digital.LocalCol) = DateAdd (Millisecond,- DatePart (Millisecond,Verdunster1B_Digital.LocalCol),Verdunster1B_Digital.LocalCol)
where Verdunster1B_Digital.LocalCol between '2013-06-09T00:00:00' and '2013-06-10T00:00:00'
and   Verdunster1B_Digital.ReasonCol = 'Zeit Ein'
and   (   MINUTE (Verdunster1B_Digital.LocalCol) = 0 
       or MINUTE (Verdunster1B_Digital.LocalCol) = 15 
       or MINUTE (Verdunster1B_Digital.LocalCol) = 30 
       or MINUTE (Verdunster1B_Digital.LocalCol) = 45)
```

It uses comands that i have never seen or used before and all things i tried didnt work. Any help in translating it into a mysql query is very welcome.

thanks!

Comment: What exactly are the "*commands that you never used before*". Seems like a pretty normal query to me (apart from the fact that the last condition could be simplified to an `IN` condition).

Comment: How about having a try yourself? Google the parts you don't know, see what they do, google what's the mysql equivalent. Simple as that.

Comment: thanks, i am not familiar with the `Inner join` and the `DateAdd` comands... thanks! ps: how would you simply the last condition?

Comment: MINUTE (Verdunster1B_Digital.LocalCol) in (0,15,30,45)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
      v.LocalCol
    , v.Funktion_Heizband_Verdunster1B
    , m.Funktion_Ventilatoren_Verdampfer_Msr
    , m.Funktion_Glykolpumpe1_Tankverbindung
FROM Verdunster1B_Digital AS v
JOIN Maschinenraum_Digital AS m ON m.LocalCol = v.LocalCol
WHERE v.LocalCol BETWEEN '20130609' AND '20130610' 
      AND v.ReasonCol = 'Zeit Ein' 
      AND MINUTE(v.LocalCol) IN (0, 15, 30, 45)
LIMIT 0, 7500
```

Comment: As MySQL doesn't support milliseconds in `datetime` columns, ising the `date_format()` seems useless. A simple `m.LocalCol = v.LocalCol` should do the same thing.

Comment: does that mean that it will simply ignore the milliseconds part?

Comment: @user2452250: there is no "milliseconds part" in MySQL.

Comment: is there a difference between join and inner join? why did you use join? thanks!

Comment: @user2452250 There's no difference.